# Are there asset management systems for PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, cmms

Are there asset management systems that use PostGIS for asset storage?

Comment: we can build one together

Answer (score 4):

I found several links that might be useful for you.

[NYSAWWA](https://nysawwa.org/about/publications) I assume the old link went to one of these publications which have now been converted to flash pages and don't seem to render to search (at least not without membership).

And DBlack's question on [gis.stackexchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4018/how-do-you-manage-existing-gis-data-and-allow-for-integration-with-an-asset-manag)

Which is not as relevant as it could be. But without more info from azteca it looks to me as though they simply use the data via sde. If your data is in postgis/sde (pg_geometry) then at least the gis data side of cityworks should be supported (contact azteca for verification).

I don't see anything on their website about the supported rdbms's (for the asset_db side) but they do state "A key element of Cityworks' design is its flexibility ". I am relatively certain they do support the major rdbms player, mssql, oracle, sybase, informix.

With the google search "cityworks database postgres" I found an interesting link for an individual that would be a good contact for you. You might take a look. I did not feel I should post here.

Comment: I think my setup for my question (and my original comment) maybe misleading. It's more of an academic question.  I've removed the junk and left the question!

Comment: NYSAWWA is a dead link.  Any idea as to what PDF was being linked?

Answer (score 4):

I think it's one of those situations where no individual is going to build a PostGIS Asset Management System without an actual project. Reason being, there are a lot of specs required that differ from jurisdiction to jurisdiction, data access, scope, and objectives; however, I've always been interested in building one. If we can find specs for an existing PMS system, we can perhaps setup a small project and build it.

Comment: I think you might be right on that.  A core PGAMS should be able to handle much of a potential system's  specs with configuration (lots of configuration for even the big&popular systems).

Comment: @JayCummins there is now an ISO 55000/1/2 standard out there. Let me know if you'd be interested in starting a project that follows those guidelines